# workflow rule not firing update field action

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

The requirement is to write a workflow rule on certain custom object for field update and the condition is "if Status__c(formula text field) value is Block and picklist value of Rule__c field is either fine or course and in this scenario if lookup field (Center__c)or (Right__C)is changed then do field update action ". Below is the criteria i wrote

```
    AND( Status__c = 'Block' , 
    OR(ISPICKVAL(Rule__c,'fine'),ISPICKVAL(Rule__c,'course')) ,
    OR(ISCHANGED(Center__c),ISCHANGED(Right__c))
     )
```

But the workflow doesnt seem to work if while editing record i keep status__c as 'block', rule__c value as 'fine'.Also the evaluation criteria is "evaluation criteria is "Every time a record is created or edited". Not sure where i went wrong

PS:this is the only workflow rue on this object and both worflow rule and action are active

Comment: Are you changing the value of center and right fields ?

Comment: did you try removing the formula field and check whether it is working or not?

Comment: As manjit5190 says, if `Center__c` or `Right__c` are not changed, then the rule will not fire.